# How to paint multiple colors on hair particles

Tags: modeling, particles, texture-painting, hair

I want to color an area of the tail purple with the shape of a triangle like in the reference in the blend file. Any idea on how to do that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a material to your tail object, give it an *Image Texture*, paint in *Texture Paint* mode, the hair will have the same color as the tail object:

[image]